# creating a SPA page using vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm implementing a SPA page by installing the webpack module and using the index.js file as an entry point.

https://github.com/lemonade4813/travel_project

[image]

<webpack.config.js>

```js
const path = require( 'path' );
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require( 'clean-webpack-plugin' );
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = (env, options) => {
  if ( options.mode === 'production' ){
    config.plugins = [...config.plugins,new CleanWebpackPlugin()];
  }
  return config;
};

const config = {
  entry: './src/js/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve( __dirname, 'dist' ),
    // publicPath: 'dist/',
    filename: '[name].[hash].js',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: [
          path.resolve( __dirname, 'src/js' )
        ],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          outputPath: 'images',
        },
      },]
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './index.html'
    })
  ]
};
```

This is <index.html>

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/css/reset.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/css/style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <h1 class ="title">Carpe Diem</h1>
    <nav class="headerNav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href ="#">로그인</a></li>
            <li><a href ="#">회원가입</a></li>
            <li><a href ="#">언어선택</a></li>  
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <nav class="mainmenu">
        <ul>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <div class="dropdown-menu">회사소개</div>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a data-link="/" href="/company">회사소개</a>
                    <a href="#">Menu1-2</a>
                    <a href="#">Menu1-3</a>
                    <a href="#">Menu1-4</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <div class="dropdown-menu">호텔예약</div>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a data-link="/hotel" href="/hotel" data-link>Menu2-1</a>
                    <a href="#">Menu2-2</a>
                    <a href="#">Menu2-3</a>
                    <a href="#">Menu2-4</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <div class="dropdown-menu">식사예약</div>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a data-link="/company" href="/company" data-link>Menu3-1</a>
                    <a href="#">Menu3-2</a>
                    <a href="#">Menu3-3</a>
                    <a href="#">Menu3-4</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <div class="dropdown-menu">환율정보</div>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <div class="dropdown-menu">항공권 예약</div>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="#">Menu3-1</a>
                    <a href="#">Menu3-2</a>
                    <a href="#">Menu3-3</a>
                    <a href="#">Menu3-4</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <div class="dropdown-menu">내 예약정보</div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <div class="mypic">
  </div>
  <div id ="root"></div>
</body>
<script src="src/js/index.js"></script>
</html>
```

And the index.js file is:

```js
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import NotFound from "./pages/NotFound";
import Hotel from "./pages/Hotel";
import Company from "./pages/Company";


const form = document.getElementById('form');

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const payload = new FormData(form);

  fetch('http://localhost:4000/add', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: payload,
  })
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data));
});


const router = async () => {
  const routes = [
      { path: "/", view: Home },
      { path: "/hotel", view: Hotel },
      { path: "/company", view: Company },
  ];

  const pageMatches = routes.map((route) => {
      return {
          route, // route: route
          isMatch: route.path === location.pathname,
      };
  });

  console.log(pageMatches)
  let match = pageMatches.find((pageMatch) => pageMatch.isMatch);

  if (!match) {
      match = {
          route: location.pathname,
          isMatch: true,
      };
      const page = new NotFound();
      document.querySelector("#root").innerHTML = await page.getHtml();
  } else {
      const page = new match.route.view();
      document.querySelector("#root").innerHTML = await page.getHtml();
  }
};


window.addEventListener("popstate", () => {
  router();
});

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  document.body.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      if (e.target.matches("[data-link]")) {
          e.preventDefault();
          history.pushState(null, null, e.target.href);
          router();
      }
  });
  router();
});
```

The JavaScript file to be used when routing is written as follows.

The file to be used for routing in the /js/pages file path was created as follows.

[image]

```js
export default class Company{
    constructor() {
        document.title = "Company";
    }
    async getHtml() {
        return `
            <h1>This is Company Introduce Page</h1>
        `;
    }
}
```

```js
export default class Home {
    constructor() {
        document.title = "Home";
    }
    async getHtml() {
        return `
            <h1>홈페이지 입니다.</h1>
        `;
    }
}
```

```js
export default class Hotel {
    constructor() {
        document.title = "호텔 예약";
    }
    async getHtml() {
        return `
            <h1>호텔 예약 페이지 입니다.</h1>
        `;
    }
}
```

But it says that path doesn't exist and gives an error like this: How should I solve it?

Comment: What kind of webserver is serving the static files and have you configured it to delegate all request to the index.html?

Comment: I did not set up a separate server to send dynamic files.

Comment: Try renaming index.js to index.mjs

Comment: I modified script file path to mjs file but it didn't work

Comment: Instead of editing this question to add every new error you get, I’d recommend creating separate questions when you get stuck. Otherwise, this “question” becomes one huge mess of debugging your entire app. Your original question, `Why am I getting a 404 for /hotel?`, has been answered, so I’d recommend you upvote/mark it as accepted, then if someone comes along with the same problem, it’s easier for them to find the problem/solution.

Comment: You seem to have dumped your entire project here. This lack of focus can make it difficult to identify the relevant failing code. Take a look at [mcve] before you post again. And use it's recommendations in future questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re implementing the routing in the front end, you’re better off using the fragment identifier, or `#`, as a prefix to your paths ([MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL#anchor)). That way you can stay on the same page and change the URL without making it ask the backend for /hotel, which is what appears to be happening in your case.

Change the links to:

```
<a data-link="/#/hotel" href="/#/hotel" data-link>Menu2-1</a>
```